# Custom Excel Function using VBA #VALUE error

Tags: excel, vba

It's my first time using VBA and I've run into an error. I've got quite a long formula in Excel that I wanted to simplify using VBA. The formula takes the temperature of air (°C) and gives the partial pressure of the water vapour (Pa). The function returns the #VALUE! error.

```
Function PartialPressureWaterVapor(Temperature)

' Sets temperature from Celcius to Kelvin
TempK = Temperature + 273.15

' Constant values for calculating PartialPressureWaterVapor when temperature is below 0 C
C01 = -5.6745359 * 10 ^ 3
C02 = 6.3925247
C03 = -9.677843 * 10 ^ -3
C04 = 6.2215701 * 10 ^ -7
C05 = 2.0747825 * 10 ^ -9
C06 = -9.484024 * 10 ^ -13
C07 = 4.1635019

' Constant values for calculating PartialPressureWaterVapor when temperature is above 0 C
C08 = -5.8002206 * 10 ^ 3
C09 = 1.3914993
C10 = -4.8640239 * 10 ^ -2
C11 = 4.1764768 * 10 ^ -5
C12 = -1.4452093 * 10 ^ -8
C13 = 6.5459673

If Temperature < 0 Then
        PartialPressureWaterVapor = Exp(C01 / TempK + C02 + C03 * TempK + C04 * TempK ^ 2 + C05 * TempK ^ 3 + C06 * TempK ^ 4 + C07 * expression.Ln(TempK))
    Else
        PartialPressureWaterVapor = Exp(C08 / TempK + C09 + C10 * TempK + C11 * TempK ^ 2 + C12 * TempK ^ 3 + C13 * expression.Ln(TempK))
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Change the instances of `expression` to `WorksheetFunction` or `Application`.

Comment: Alright, I changed the expression and the function works now. So close yet so far...
Thanks a lot Ben!